# Loading Image from URL

Tags: uno-platform

I’m working on a UNO-WASM project using images hosted on a webserver.

There is no problem displaying the images via Binding the URL to the Source property of the Image, but if I wish do the same thing in code behind (working perfectly in UWP):

`image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri( ... ));`

nothings happen.
Any clue?
Michael

Comment: Can you add the URL you are using? I am interested especially in whether it is a `ms-appx:///` URI or something else

Comment: URI: It's .Net Core webservice: 
http://wsmshop.storecheck.tech/BaseDoc/GetImageByPK/p/1084